# XML Path, data extraction from table and with merged nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

I was trying to get from my table a XML file in a particular format.

My table is the next:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TripHistoryTest','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TripHistoryTest
create table TripHistoryTest
(
    [BarCode] nvarchar(100),
    [PassengerName] nvarchar(100),
    [SegmentType] char(1),
    [Flight1_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_ToTime] nvarchar(100)
)

insert into TripHistoryTest
(
    [BarCode],
    [PassengerName],
    [SegmentType],
    [Flight1_From],
    [Flight1_FromTime] ,
    [Flight1_To] ,
    [Flight1_ToTime] ,
    [Flight2_From],
    [Flight2_FromTime],
    [Flight2_To],
    [Flight2_ToTime],
    [Flight3_From],
    [Flight3_FromTime],
    [Flight3_To],
    [Flight3_ToTime],
    [Flight4_From],
    [Flight4_FromTime],
    [Flight4_To],
    [Flight4_ToTime],
    [Hotel_From],
    [Hotel_FromTime],
    [Hotel_To],
    [Hotel_ToTime],
    [Train_From] ,
    [Train_FromTime] ,
    [Train_To] ,
    [Train_ToTime] ,
    [Car_From],
    [Car_FromTime],
    [Car_To],
    [Car_ToTime] 
)
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
    'MILAN', '06:00', 'NAPOLI', '07:00',
    'NAPOLI', '08:00', 'BUDAPEST', '10:00',
    'BUDAPEST', '11:00', 'CRAIOVA', '13:00',
    'CRAIOVA', '14:00', 'ROMA', '16:00', 
    '','','','',
    '','','','',
    '','','',''
UNION ALL
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
    'ROMA', '17:00', 'TORINO', '18:00',
    'TORINO', '19:00', 'MADRID', '20:00',
    '','','','',
    '','','','', 
    '','','','',
    '','','','',
    '','','',''
UNION ALL
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
    'MADRID', '21:00', 'MANILA', '23:00',
    '','','','',
    '','','','',
    '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
UNION ALL
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'T', 
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', 
    '','','','',
    'MANILA','23:30','CALBAYOG','23:40',
    '','','',''
UNION ALL
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'H', 
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', 
    'LASTHOPEHOTEL','23:50','LASTHOPEHOTEL','06:00',
    '','','','',
    '','','',''
UNION ALL
select 
    'BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'C', 
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', 
    '','','','',
    '','','','',
    'CALBAYOG','07:00','MARIANA TRENCH',''
```

I'm simulating what I have in the system now, so here are some notes:

SegmentType:

F : Flight
T : Train
C : Car
H : Hotel

I've done a query using XML PATH with no success, here is my output:

```
select
    -- ###############
    -- ### BARCODE ###
    -- ###############
    A.[BarCode],
    -- ################
    -- ### TRAVELER ###
    -- ################
    (
        select distinct
            B.[PassengerName]
        from
            TripHistoryTest B
        where   1=1
                and A.[BarCode] = B.[BarCode]
        group by B.[PassengerName]
        for xml path ('Passenger'), root('PassengerList'), TYPE
    ),
    -- ###################
    -- ### AIR SEGMENT ###
    -- ###################
    (
        select distinct
            case when C.[Flight1_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight1_From] end as "AirSeg/Flight_From",
            case when C.[Flight1_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight1_FromTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_FromTime",
            case when C.[Flight1_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight1_To] end as "AirSeg/Flight_To",
            case when C.[Flight1_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight1_ToTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_ToTime",
            '',
            case when C.[Flight2_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight2_From] end as "AirSeg/Flight_From",
            case when C.[Flight2_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight2_FromTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_FromTime",
            case when C.[Flight2_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight2_To] end as "AirSeg/Flight_To",
            case when C.[Flight2_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight2_ToTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_ToTime",
            '',
            case when C.[Flight3_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight3_From] end as "AirSeg/Flight_From",
            case when C.[Flight3_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight3_FromTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_FromTime",
            case when C.[Flight3_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight3_To] end as "AirSeg/Flight_To",
            case when C.[Flight3_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight3_ToTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_ToTime",
            '',
            case when C.[Flight4_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight4_From] end as "AirSeg/Flight_From",
            case when C.[Flight4_From] = '' then null else C.[Flight4_FromTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_FromTime",
            case when C.[Flight4_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight4_To] end as "AirSeg/Flight_To",
            case when C.[Flight4_To] = '' then null else C.[Flight4_ToTime] end as "AirSeg/Flight_ToTime"
        from
            TripHistoryTest C
        where   1=1
                and A.[BarCode] = C.[BarCode]
                and C.[SegmentType] = 'F'
        group by 
            C.[Flight1_From], C.[Flight1_FromTime], C.[Flight2_From], C.[Flight2_FromTime], C.[Flight3_From], C.[Flight3_FromTime],
            C.[Flight4_From], C.[Flight4_FromTime], C.[Flight1_To], C.[Flight1_ToTime], C.[Flight2_To], C.[Flight2_ToTime], C.[Flight3_To], C.[Flight3_ToTime],
            C.[Flight4_To], C.[Flight4_ToTime]
        for xml path ('Segment_List'), TYPE 
    )
from 
    TripHistoryTest A
group by
    A.[BarCode], A.[PassengerName], A.[Flight1_From], A.[Flight1_FromTime], A.[Flight2_From], A.[Flight2_FromTime], A.[Flight3_From], A.[Flight3_FromTime],
    A.[Flight4_From], A.[Flight4_FromTime], A.[Flight1_To], A.[Flight1_ToTime], A.[Flight2_To], A.[Flight2_ToTime], A.[Flight3_To], A.[Flight3_ToTime],
    A.[Flight4_To], A.[Flight4_ToTime]
order by A.[Flight1_FromTime] asc
for xml path ('BARCODE'), root ('BARCODE_List')
```

My final output was:

```
<BARCODE_List>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
</BARCODE_List>
```

However, this is not what i'm expecting, i would like to have something like this:

```
<BARCODE_List>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
</BARCODE_List>
```

Is there is an easy way to do this? Obviously I would like to include the Hotel, Car and Train segment as they are important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by using XQuery and FLWOR expression. All flight segments (F : Flight) organized as rows via `UNION ALL`. The final XML is shaped directly via FLWOR expressions.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TripHistoryTest TABLE
(
    [BarCode] nvarchar(100),
    [PassengerName] nvarchar(100),
    [SegmentType] char(1),
    [Flight1_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight1_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight2_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight3_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Flight4_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Hotel_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Train_ToTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_From] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_FromTime] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_To] nvarchar(100),
    [Car_ToTime] nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TripHistoryTest
(
    [BarCode],
    [PassengerName],
    [SegmentType],
    [Flight1_From],
    [Flight1_FromTime] ,
    [Flight1_To] ,
    [Flight1_ToTime] ,
    [Flight2_From],
    [Flight2_FromTime],
    [Flight2_To],
    [Flight2_ToTime],
    [Flight3_From],
    [Flight3_FromTime],
    [Flight3_To],
    [Flight3_ToTime],
    [Flight4_From],
    [Flight4_FromTime],
    [Flight4_To],
    [Flight4_ToTime],
    [Hotel_From],
    [Hotel_FromTime],
    [Hotel_To],
    [Hotel_ToTime],
    [Train_From] ,
    [Train_FromTime] ,
    [Train_To] ,
    [Train_ToTime] ,
    [Car_From],
    [Car_FromTime],
    [Car_To],
    [Car_ToTime] 
)
VALUES
('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
'MILAN', '06:00', 'NAPOLI', '07:00',
'NAPOLI', '08:00', 'BUDAPEST', '10:00',
'BUDAPEST', '11:00', 'CRAIOVA', '13:00',
'CRAIOVA', '14:00', 'ROMA', '16:00', 
'','','','',
'','','','',
'','','','')
,('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
'ROMA', '17:00', 'TORINO', '18:00',
'TORINO', '19:00', 'MADRID', '20:00',
'','','','',
'','','','', 
'','','','',
'','','','',
'','','','')
,('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'F', 
'MADRID', '21:00', 'MANILA', '23:00',
'','','','',
'','','','',
'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
,('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'T', 
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', 
'','','','',
'MANILA','23:30','CALBAYOG','23:40',
'','','','')
,('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'H', 
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', 
'LASTHOPEHOTEL','23:50','LASTHOPEHOTEL','06:00',
'','','','',
'','','','')
,('BR666999', 'KETYM PORTA', 'C', 
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', 
'','','','',
'','','','',
'CALBAYOG','07:00','MARIANA TRENCH','');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- XQuery and FLWOR
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT BarCode, PassengerName
        , Flight1_From AS Flight_From
        , Flight1_FromTime AS Flight_FromTime
        , Flight1_To AS Flight_To
        , Flight1_ToTime AS Flight_ToTime
    FROM @TripHistoryTest
    WHERE SegmentType = 'F' AND Flight1_From != ''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BarCode, PassengerName
        , Flight2_From AS Flight_From
        , Flight2_FromTime AS Flight_FromTime
        , Flight2_To AS Flight_To
        , Flight2_ToTime AS Flight_ToTime
    FROM @TripHistoryTest
    WHERE SegmentType = 'F' AND Flight2_From != ''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BarCode, PassengerName
        , Flight3_From AS Flight_From
        , Flight3_FromTime AS Flight_FromTime
        , Flight3_To AS Flight_To
        , Flight3_ToTime AS Flight_ToTime
    FROM @TripHistoryTest
    WHERE SegmentType = 'F' AND Flight3_From != ''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BarCode, PassengerName
        , Flight4_From AS Flight_From
        , Flight4_FromTime AS Flight_FromTime
        , Flight4_To AS Flight_To
        , Flight4_ToTime AS Flight_ToTime
    FROM @TripHistoryTest
    WHERE SegmentType = 'F' AND Flight4_From <> ''
)
SELECT (SELECT * FROM rs
ORDER BY Flight_FromTime
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('<BARCODE_List><BARCODE>
<BarCode>{data(root/r[1]/BarCode)}</BarCode>
<PassengerList>
{
    for $p in distinct-values(/root/r/PassengerName)
    return <Passenger>
            <PassengerName>{$p}</PassengerName>
        </Passenger>
}
</PassengerList>
<Segment_List>
{
    for $x in /root/r
    return <AirSeg>
            {$x/Flight_From}
            {$x/Flight_FromTime}
            {$x/Flight_To}
            {$x/Flight_ToTime}
        </AirSeg>
}
</Segment_List>
</BARCODE></BARCODE_List>');
```

> Output

```
<BARCODE_List>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
</BARCODE_List>
```

Comment: This works great! I'm now trying to add more segments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Flightfrom and Flightto data. They need to be in multiple rows instead of multiple columns in order for the xml to be generated as requested:

```
;WITH cte_flight([BarCode],[PassengerName],[Flight_From],[Flight_To],Flight_FromTime,Flight_ToTime)
AS
(
    SELECT [BarCode],[PassengerName],[Flight1_From],[Flight1_To],[Flight1_FromTime],[Flight1_ToTime]
    FROM TripHistoryTest
    WHERE [SegmentType] = 'F'
    AND [Flight1_From]<>N''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [BarCode],[PassengerName],[Flight2_From],[Flight2_To],[Flight2_FromTime],[Flight2_ToTime]
    FROM TripHistoryTest
    WHERE [SegmentType] = 'F'
    AND [Flight2_From]<>N''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [BarCode],[PassengerName],[Flight3_From],[Flight3_To],[Flight3_FromTime],[Flight3_ToTime]
    FROM TripHistoryTest
    WHERE [SegmentType] = 'F'
    AND [Flight3_From]<>N''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [BarCode],[PassengerName],[Flight4_From],[Flight4_To],[Flight4_FromTime],[Flight4_ToTime]
    FROM TripHistoryTest
    WHERE [SegmentType] = 'F'
    AND [Flight4_From]<>N''
)
select
     A.[BarCode],
    (
        select distinct
            B.[PassengerName]
        from
            TripHistoryTest B
        where   1=1
                and A.[BarCode] = B.[BarCode]
        group by B.[PassengerName]
        for xml path ('Passenger'), root('PassengerList'), TYPE
    ),
    (
        SELECT
            C.[Flight_From] as "Flight_From",
            C.[Flight_FromTime] as "Flight_FromTime",
            C.[Flight_To] as "Flight_To",
            C.[Flight_ToTime] as "Flight_ToTime"
        from
            cte_flight C
        where   1=1
                and A.[BarCode] = C.[BarCode]
                and C.[PassengerName]=A.[PassengerName]
        order by C.[Flight_FromTime]
        for xml path('AirSeg'), Root ('Segment_List'), TYPE 
    )
from 
    TripHistoryTest A
GROUP BY A.BarCode,A.[PassengerName]
for xml path ('BARCODE'), root ('BARCODE_List')


<BARCODE_List>
  <BARCODE>
    <BarCode>BR666999</BarCode>
    <PassengerList>
      <Passenger>
        <PassengerName>KETYM PORTA</PassengerName>
      </Passenger>
    </PassengerList>
    <Segment_List>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MILAN</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>06:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>NAPOLI</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>07:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>NAPOLI</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>08:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>BUDAPEST</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>10:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>BUDAPEST</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>11:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>CRAIOVA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>13:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>CRAIOVA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>14:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>ROMA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>16:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>ROMA</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>17:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>TORINO</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>18:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>TORINO</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>19:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MADRID</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>20:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
      <AirSeg>
        <Flight_From>MADRID</Flight_From>
        <Flight_FromTime>21:00</Flight_FromTime>
        <Flight_To>MANILA</Flight_To>
        <Flight_ToTime>23:00</Flight_ToTime>
      </AirSeg>
    </Segment_List>
  </BARCODE>
</BARCODE_List>
```